# Clip values between a minimum and maximum allowed value in R

Tags: r, vectorization, clip, clamp

In Mathematica there is the command `Clip[x, {min, max}]`
which gives `x` for `min<=x<=max`, `min` for `x<min` and and `max` for `x>max`, see

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Clip.html  ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170816183037/http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Clip.html))

What would be the fastest way to achieve this in R? Ideally it should be a function that is listable, and should ideally work on either a single value, vector, matrix or dataframe...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`Rcpp` has `clamp` for this:

```
cppFunction('NumericVector rcpp_clip( NumericVector x, double a, double b){
    return clamp( a, x, b ) ;
}')
```

Here is a quick benchmark showing how it performs against other methods discussed :

```
pmin_pmax_clip <- function(x, a, b) pmax(a, pmin(x, b) )
ifelse_clip <- function(x, a, b) {
  ifelse(x <= a,  a, ifelse(x >= b, b, x))
}
operations_clip <- function(x, a, b) {
  a + (x-a > 0)*(x-a) - (x-b > 0)*(x-b)
}
x <- rnorm( 10000 )
require(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark( 
  pmin_pmax_clip( x, -2, 2 ), 
  rcpp_clip( x, -2, 2 ), 
  ifelse_clip( x, -2, 2 ), 
  operations_clip( x, -2, 2 )
)
# Unit: microseconds
#                        expr      min        lq   median        uq       max
# 1     ifelse_clip(x, -2, 2) 2809.211 3812.7350 3911.461 4481.0790 43244.543
# 2 operations_clip(x, -2, 2)  228.282  248.2500  266.605 1120.8855 40703.937
# 3  pmin_pmax_clip(x, -2, 2)  260.630  284.0985  308.426  336.9280  1353.721
# 4       rcpp_clip(x, -2, 2)   65.413   70.7120   84.568   92.2875  1097.039
```

Comment: Those times are pretty rockin'.

Comment: Just pasting the lines for the clamp code in a console session is obviously not what you intended us Rcpp virgins to be doing.

Comment: Almost. See my use of `cppFunction` in my edit. (but you need the current devel version of `Rcpp` because `clamp` has been fixed since the last release).

Comment: Very cool. I'm shocked and baffled at how bad the `operations_clip()` times are .... *sometimes*. Any ideas why the **max** values are quite so much larger than the **min** values for all of these functions?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is about memory allocation. `operations_clip` performs a lot of them, so my guess is that sometimes it takes longer.

Comment: @RomainFrancois Just to come back to this - what would be the recommended way to do this for the case where lower and upper limits a and b were not doubles but NumericVectors? Would using RcppArmadillo x.elem(arma::find(x < lower)) = lower.elem(arma::find(x < lower));
x.elem(arma::find(x > upper)) = upper.elem(arma::find(x > upper)); be an OK approach or would there be better ways? Or would using Rcpp sugar functions pmin and pmax pmax(lower, pmin(x, upper)) also work? And in Rcpp code above I think clamp(a, x, b) should be clamp(x, a, b) right?

Answer (score 23):

Here's a method with nested `pmin` and `pmax` setting the bounds:

```
 fenced.var <- pmax( LB, pmin( var, UB))
```

It will be difficult to find a method that is faster. Wrapped in a function that defaults to a range of 3 and 7:

```
fence <- function(vec, UB=7, LB=3) pmax( LB, pmin( vec, UB))

> fence(1:10)
 [1] 3 3 3 4 5 6 7 7 7 7
```

Comment: Very elegant - that's great!

Comment: I use this one a lot. I have a large dataset that has several variables that are not plausibly real below 0 and that should be sensible constrained at the high end as well. The real trick is remembering to set the max with `pmin` and set the min with `pmax`.

Comment: Your 'It will be difficult to find a method that is faster' obviously motivated me to have a look.

Comment: Yeah. It still wins the compactness prize ... so far.

Comment: I think the function's arguments UB and LB should be reversed.  I suspect `fence <- function(vec, LB=3, UB=7) pmax( LB, pmin( vec, UB))` is really what you're after

Comment: @jf328: You might want to present a counter-example since my experiments showed it to be working in what I thought was a perfectly reasonable manner.  `pmin( pmax( matrix(1:10,2), 4), 6)` Probably best to do this with a new question.

Comment: @42- interesting. You have to put the scalar (4 and 6) as the second argument. If you put them as the first argument as in your answer, then it returns a vector, not a matrix. And the pmax/pmin document does say it only returns a vector.

Answer (score 11):

Here's one function that will work for both vectors and matrices.

```
myClip <- function(x, a, b) {
    ifelse(x <= a,  a, ifelse(x >= b, b, x))
}

myClip(x = 0:10, a = 3,b = 7)
#  [1] 3 3 3 3 4 5 6 7 7 7 7

myClip(x = matrix(1:12/10, ncol=4), a=.2, b=0.7)
# myClip(x = matrix(1:12/10, ncol=4), a=.2, b=0.7)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]  0.2  0.4  0.7  0.7
# [2,]  0.2  0.5  0.7  0.7
# [3,]  0.3  0.6  0.7  0.7
```

And here's another:

```
myClip2 <- function(x, a, b) {
    a + (x-a > 0)*(x-a) - (x-b > 0)*(x-b)
}

myClip2(-10:10, 0, 4)
# [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
```

Comment: Great!! Thanks so much!! My function for this was waaayy slower, but this works quite fast!

Comment: This should be in R's base library!

Answer (score 4):

I believe that would be [`clamp()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/raster/versions/2.6-7/topics/clamp) from the `raster` package.

```
library(raster)
clamp(x, lower=-Inf, upper=Inf, ...)
```

Comment: Wondering why no one has done timings on these alternatives?